# Convenient espresso shot container?

Tags: espresso

My friend recently gifted me a Breville ESP8XL. I'm looking for a convenient sealed (portable) container to carry (up to 3) espresso shots to work for the post-lunch slump. I couldn't find anything on Amazon. Does anybody use something similar to this?

Comment: Do you need the espresso to stay hot, or is it alright for it to go cold (e.g. if it is going to be mixed with hot or iced water at drinking time)?

Answer (score 3):

A very small thermos may be the answer. Quality made 50 ml (~2 oz.) thermos could be enough for a double shot. I have checked and found a few with a Google search.

Comment: Ewwwww! Thermos coffee... ^_^

Comment: @Stephie :) Better than instant coffee, worse than fresh brewed.